# How to display two different dates on my title page?

Tags: datetime

My aim is to display both the experiment and the report date on the title page of my report; how can I achieve my goal?

Edit: Part of my code before the main part is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4, color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document} 
\title{Understanding Semiconductor Lasers}
\author{Ongun Ar\i sev}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\newpage
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? Possibly provide a MWE as to what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the default document classes (including `article`), you can just add another date to `\date`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{Understanding Semiconductor Lasers}
\author{Ongun Ar\i sev}
\date{\today{} and January 1, 2013}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, thanks. I am pretty new in LaTeX so forgive my question. Could I also add Experiment date like some sort of modifier in front of one of the dates?

Comment: @Vesnog: Yes, you can do `\date{Report: \today{}; Experiment: January 1, 2013}` if you wish.

Comment: Can I have them pasted on separate lines? Figured it out by putting \\ but if I wanted to separate them more is there an option allowing that?

Comment: @Vesnog: You can use `\\[<len>]` where you specify `<len>`. For example, `\\[\baselineskip]` inserts an empty line. Or `\\[50pt]` will insert a 50pt gap.

Comment: Well thanks for that they will definitely prove useful.